# How to change the output format in the inline if statement of outputtext?

Tags: apex, outputtext, format

There are some codes like below:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!IF(item.FinishedDate__c == null, 'Not Finished', item.FinishedDate__c)}"/>
```

The item.FinishedDate__c is defined as Date, and I want the format of output is "yyyy-MM-dd", so I tried to modeify the codes like below but failed:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!IF(item.FinishedDate__c == null, 'Not Finished', {0,date,yyyy-MM-dd})}">
    <apex:param value="{!item.FinishedDate__c}" />
</apex:outputText>
```

Could someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: what exactly is the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the logic in two `<apex:outputText` and rendered it based on the condition  `item.FinishedDate__c==null` or `item.FinishedDate__c!=null`. It will show `Not Finished` (first `<apex:outputText`) when your value is null and when the value is not null it will display the Date as per your required format (second `<apex:outputText`).

Note that the below code is not compiled one and you may have to fix any syntax error.

```
<apex:outputText value="Not Finished" rendered="{!item.FinishedDate__c == null}"></apex:outputText>
<apex:outputText value="{0,date,yyyy-MM-dd}" rendered="{!item.FinishedDate__c != null}">
    <apex:param value="{!item.FinishedDate__c}" />
</apex:outputText>
```